# How to capture all requests with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to create a javascript interceptor in order to capture all requests that i see in the network tab and print them in the website.
Is that possible?
I have found the following code but it doesnt seem to work

```
     let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
 // do something with the method, url and etc.
 console.log(url);
 this.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // do something with the response text
  console.log('load: ' + this.responseText);
 });

 return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is that possible?

No.

> have found the following code but it doesnt seem to work

That will only intercept requests made using the XMLHttpRequest object (not by anything else such as `fetch`, `<script src="...">`, `<img src="...">` etc.).

Comment: Ok i want only the XMLHttpRequest requests. How can i do it?